# How do you convert GEOIP2 Geolitecity in .csv packages to GEOIP2 .mmdb databse?

Tags: logstash, maxmind

How do you convert GEOIP2 Geolitecity in .csv packages to GEOIP2 .mmdb databse, of which I can use in Logstash? Basically, I am trying to create a custom IP database for company internal network, how do i do that?